# Python Main Function Command Line Argument Long List

Tags: command

I'm trying to make a simple main function for a Caesars Shift cryptography program, however I'm not quite sure how to configure all this command line opt/arg stuff.  I want to configure the program to accept command line arguments like so:

```
./caesars.py -e 13 message to encrypt
```

with 13 being the amount of shifts and the following lines to be the message to encrypt.  I have the functions defined, but I am just not sure how to configure the opt arg stuff to accept the first argument after argv[1] to be the key, then everything after that to get split into a list/long string.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    global decoder
    global encoder

    if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
        usage()

    # read the commandline options
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hd:e:", ¬
        ["help","decode","encode"])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print str(err)
        usage()
    for o,a in opts:
        if o in ("-h","--help"):
            usage()
    elif o in ("-d","--decode"):
        decode = True
    elif o in ("-e", "--encode"):
        encode = True
    else:
        assert False,"Unhandled Option"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, you should look into [docopt](http://docopt.org). While I have never used it myself, it's very popular and should be perfect for you.

Comment: Alright, thank you.  I've looked for stuff on opt but haven't found much in depth coverage.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Many people swear by docopt rather than anything built into Python. It seems very comprehensive and customizable.